# Repaint() doesn't work when called from new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I want to do a sorting animation. I've got a **JFrame** with **GridLayout(1,3)** because I have 3 sorting alghorithms. In each cell I have a **JPanel** with **BorderLayout()**. In the **center** of the **JPanel** I have the numbers and for each number a stick with different widths(I placed them horizontally). For each type of sorting I need a thread to call them. So I created class **SortThread** which does my sorting (it extends **JThread**). Each pair of numbers and sticks are painted on the center panel with class **StickNumber** which extends **JLabel**. The problem is when I start the thread. The **repaint()** method doesn't seem to work.

Here is class **SortThread**:

```
public class SortThread extends Thread{
private JPanel sortPanel;
private StickNumber[] listOfNumbers;

public SortThread(JPanel sortPanel)
{
    this.sortPanel = sortPanel;
    Component[] components = sortPanel.getComponents();
    listOfNumbers = new StickNumber[components.length];
    for(int i = 0; i<components.length; i++)
        listOfNumbers[i] = (StickNumber) components[i];
}

public SortThread(){}

public void bubbleSort()
{
    boolean swapped = true;
    int j = 0;
    StickNumber tmp;

    while (swapped) {
        swapped = false;
        j++;
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfNumbers.length - j; i++) {                                       
            if (listOfNumbers[i].getValue() > listOfNumbers[i+1].getValue()) {                          
                tmp = listOfNumbers[i];
                listOfNumbers[i]=listOfNumbers[i+1];
                listOfNumbers[i+1]=tmp;
                swapped = true;
                sortPanel.validate();
                sortPanel.repaint();
            }
        }                
    }
}
public void run(){
    bubbleSort();
}
```

Here is the listener for my button which starts the thread:

```
ActionListener sortListener = new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(sortFlag == false)
            {
                sortFlag = true;
                SortThread thread1= new SortThread(centerPanel1);
                thread1.start();
                appFrame.validate();
                appFrame.repaint();
            }

        }
    };
    sortButton.addActionListener(sortListener);
```

**StickNumber** class:

```
private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {  

    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    String number = Integer.toString(value);
    if(dimension!=0)
        setText(number);
    g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Float(dimension*10, 5, height+dimension*10, 5));

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    doDrawing(g);
}
```

Comment: I can't comment specifically on your problem, but in swing all interaction with the UI should be done from one thread. Have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/

Comment: `repaint` can be done off the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). The `validate` off EDT should be `revalidate`. My guess is that you're not giving any time for the EDT to catch up with repainting. That and `bubbleSort` doesn't actually appear to do anything (that appears in painting the component).

Comment: so I should use sleep() for each iteration in bubbleSort?

Comment: This looks perfect for a SwingWorker

Comment: I notice this too but I can't manage to make it work

Comment: I use sleep(1000) inside bubbleSort() and call the method in doInBackground() and it didn't work.... then I removed all the JPanel's content after each iteration and add them back in the new order.... still nothing.... it removed all my JPanel's content though but it didn't put it back...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SwingWorker, assuming your code does what it should and your problems is the EDT is blocked:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SortSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

    private JPanel sortPanel;
    private StickNumber[] listOfNumbers;

    public SortSwingWorker(JPanel sortPanel) {
        this.sortPanel = sortPanel;
        Component[] components = sortPanel.getComponents();
        listOfNumbers = new StickNumber[components.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < components.length; i++) {
            listOfNumbers[i] = (StickNumber) components[i];
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        boolean swapped = true;
        int j = 0;
        StickNumber tmp;

        while (swapped) {
            swapped = false;
            j++;
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfNumbers.length - j; i++) {
                if (listOfNumbers[i].getValue() > listOfNumbers[i + 1].getValue()) {
                    tmp = listOfNumbers[i];
                    listOfNumbers[i] = listOfNumbers[i + 1];
                    listOfNumbers[i + 1] = tmp;
                    swapped = true;
                    publish(null);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Object> list) {
        sortPanel.validate();
        sortPanel.repaint();
    }

    //dummy class
    private class StickNumber extends Component {

        public Integer getValue() {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```